# Instalação bibliotecas jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, ipython-notebook

Estou tentando importar o pandas no jupyter notebook mais ele me da o seguinte erro:

```
import pandas as pd
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Já tentei também pelo spyder e retorna mesmo erro. Alguém já passou por isso e se já como resolveu.

Answer (score 1):

Isso significa que o pandas não esta instalado pois estar tentando encontrar o módulo dele.

Você pode usar o pip:

```
pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

Dois possíveis problemas:
Esse * que você está utilizando. O correto é dessa forma:

```py
import pandas as pd
```

Caso o * seja apenas um erro de digitação ou esteja apenas no retorno do erro, você precisa instalar a biblioteca.
Abra o Anaconda Prompt e digite o seguinte comando:

```
pip install pandas
```